# Replace packages unsupported in Ubuntu with packages from Debian

Tags: ubuntu, debian, upgrade

On an installation of Ubuntu 18.04, `ubuntu-support-status --show-unsupported` shows several unsupported packages. This is a known issue with Ubuntu that the LTS promise is only for packages in `main`, but many setups require packages from `universe` and `multiverse`. Now, the clean solution would be to use Debian instead. However, this is a VM in a computing center, and they do not offer Debian at the moment. So I'm stuck with Ubuntu.

What about replacing the unsupported packages with packages from the Debian `main` repository? Any experiences with that? What would be the necessary technical steps?

I'm also contemplating using `do-release-upgrade` in order to go to 19.04, hoping that it will support all the relevant packages.

Any other ideas how to deal with this situation?

**Addendum:** To some degree, a solution is to use an nspawn container. I give a [basic howto on setting up such a container](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/539620/145107) (does not address private user configuration, though) and [some comments on how to get XFS filesystem quotas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/539642/145107) inside of the container.

Side note: The computing center in the meantime offered me to install Debian on the VM, so the problem no longer persists for me. But maybe this will be helpful to others. I also like to add that I find the current state of Ubuntu unacceptable; you cannot have unsupported packages on a production system. Some of the unsupported packages are pretty standard ones (such as `nslcd` and `fail2ban`), and are suggested by Ubuntu's official howtos.

Answer (score 1):

- Have your system use as most official packages as possible, then build from sources everything else.

Or:

- Find a simple way to use Debian from Ubuntu, like a `chroot` jail, or by using Docker.

Comment: I'm playing with nspawn now. Thanks for the inspiration!